# Is the universe we know just shaped due to time?

Tags: speed-of-light, spacetime, time

Call me a daydreamer, but I could not stop myself for asking this question.

I was idle when something ticked me and struck my head. I was thinking about universe, speed of light, and how time works. I imagined that what if there was another world where time was so slow that light travels at 1 m/s w.r.t. the present world. What I mean to say is that imagine the world which has time passing so slow that in that world, the speed of light is 1 m/s w.r.t. the present world. I was just wondering, would that be the possible 'speed limit' of that world?

I think probably the answer is yes but if the answer is yes, does that mean that the universe is shaped the way we know is just due to how time behaves?

I dont know but i do not think any scientist has said that universe is just shaped due to how time behaves but i think the time is not dependent on universe, the universe is dependent on time.

Am i correct?

Comment: There is no way to compare absolute speeds of anything between two universes. If the universes have access to each other to perform the comparison, then they are not distinct universes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. Our universe would look very different if time traveled that slow. If you want to viscerally experience a world with a reduced speed of light, try this free game developed by MIT students, A Slower Speed of Light: http://gamelab.mit.edu/games/a-slower-speed-of-light/

Comment: Always liked that game and the Devil's Tuning Fork - just wish they had been developed further.

Comment: Actually, i basically asked whether time frames or shapes the universe, and it is not vice versa. I too can visualize the same but my question is, is it so that time only shapes the universe? P.S. Thanks for the link...